# Sharepoint: Uploading sandboxed solutions without needing to be an administrator?

Tags: sharepoint

I want to develop and deploy sandboxed Visual Studio 2010 sharepoint solutions.

I've developed against a local copy of sharepoint foundation, but want to be able to upload now to our departmental site within sharepoint.

However I don't have permissions to do this and have been told that it would require me to be a site collection administrator, something that people are unwilling to give as it would mean I would have access to some other more sensitive sites, which I can understand.

So, is this just a limitation of sharepoint, or can someone suggest a workaround that would allow me to upload these sandboxed solutions withouth being made a site collection administrator?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mostly true that you need to be a site collection administrator to deploy sandboxed solutions. However, a solution that does not contain an assembly is still able to be deployed by a user with "Full Control" privileges on the site collection root.